# Ambiguous reference to member 'decodeIfPresent(_:forKey:)

Tags: swift, codable

Is there anyway to make codable from [String: Any]?
I'm using SwiftyJSON and looks like the encode part does not give any error

```
struct MyClass: Codable {
    var my_label: [String: Any]?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case my_label   = "my_label"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        my_label = try values.decodeIfPresent([String: Any].self, forKey: .my_label)

    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encodeIfPresent(JSON(my_label as Any), forKey: .my_label)
    }
}
```

some of the example show my_label will look like this, though there's no guarantee that's why it is Any

```
            "my_label": {
                "condition": {
                    "IsOpen": "Yes"
                },
                "label": "Test Completed:"
            },
```

Comment: You cannot decode **Any**-thing which is or contains `Any`. Everything must conform to `(De)codable`. And as you specify `CodingKeys` anyway get rid of this ugly *snake-cased* variable name.

Comment: `decodeIfPresent` expects an argument conforming to `Decodable`. `Any` doesn't conform to `Decodable`, so `Dictionary<String,Any>` doesn't either.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSONSerialization` but with `Decodable` `Any` can't be used

```
do {
    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [String: Any]
    if let res = json["my_label"] as? [String:Any] {
        print(res)
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Or

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let myLabel: MyLabel

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case myLabel = "my_label"
    }
}

struct MyLabel: Codable {
    let condition: Condition
    let label: String
}

struct Condition: Codable {
    let isOpen: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case isOpen = "IsOpen"
    }
}
```